Lua World of Warcraft: memory leak with array
This is my first add-on and my first Lua program.
I capture the events of the combat log.
In a table (db1) I store the damage of each second.
db1 is limited to 50 entries.
Initially the addon occupies 39 kb, but as time goes by, the memory it occupies increases (observed with GetAddOnMemoryUsage("GraphDPS")).
Even by triggering a collectgarbage("collect") when the memory used reaches double the initial memory. I always end up with a freeze.
Does anyone have an idea?
-- ================================= VARIABLES ================================== --
-- Globals, only used when login and log out
GDPS_damae = 0
GDPS_db1 = {}
GDPS_db3 = {}
GDPS_frgfh = 238
GDPS_frgfw = 83
GDPS_unvu = {}
-- Locals
local coei = nil                         -- combat : CombatLog Event Infos
local colib = "Dernier combat"           -- combat : "Dernier combat" ou combat actuel"
local cosc = 0                           -- combat : compteur de seconde du combat en cours
local damae = 0                          -- data : biggest dps ever
local datalc = 0                         -- data :total amount last combat
local db1 = {}                           -- database 1
local db1l = 50                          -- database 1 limit
local db1le = {nil, nil}                 -- database : database 1 last entry
local db1nv = 0                          -- database : database 1 number of values
local db1nvn = 0                         -- database : database 1 number of values numerical
local db3 = {}                           -- database : database 3
local evt = ""                           -- event : type
local eva = 0                            -- event : amount
local evsn = ""                          -- event : swing or spell
local fra = 0                            -- frames alpha
local tic = 0                            -- timer : every second in combat
local tmce = 0                           -- timestamp : combat end (PLAYER_REGEN_ENABLED)
local tmcel = 0                          -- timestamp : combat end
local tmdce = 0                          -- timestamp : combat end delta
local tmia = 0                           -- timestamp : timstamp in analyse
local tmiaa = 0                          -- timestamp : timestamp in analyse amount
local tmlcs = 0                          -- timestamp : timestamp last combat start
local tmoe = 0                           -- timestamp : timestamp of event
local tmprd = 0                          -- timestamp : timestamp combat start (PLAYER_REGEN_DISABLED)
local unUID = UnitGUID("player")         -- units : player
local unUIDe = ""                        -- units : of event
local unvu = {}                          -- units : list of valid units
unvu[unUID] = true
-- ============================= LOCALISED FUNCTIONS ============================ --
local C_Timer = C_Timer
local CombatLogGetCurrentEventInfo = CombatLogGetCurrentEventInfo
local CreateFrame = CreateFrame
local mathfloor = math.floor
local tableremove = table.remove 
local type = type
-- ================================= FONCTIONS ================================== --
-- obtenir timestamps courant sans virgule
---@return number
local function tmr()
    return mathfloor(time())
end
-- mise à jour du plus gros dps enregistré
local function daum()
    if tmiaa > damae then
        damae = tmiaa
    end     
end
-- efface la plus ancienne donnée dans db1
local function db1doe()
    db1nv = db1nv - 1
    if type(db1[1][2]) == "number" then
        db1nvn    = db1nvn - 1
    end 
    tableremove(db1, 1)
end
-- ajoute une entrée dans db1
---@param t number
---@param v number or string
local function db1ad(t, v)
    if #db1 == db1l then
        db1doe()
    end
    db1[#db1+1] = {t, v} --
    db1nv = db1nv + 1
    if type(v) == "number" then
        db1nvn = db1nvn + 1
        daum()
    end
    db1le = {t, v} --
end
-- =================== FRAMES ET FONCTIONS PROPRES AUX FRAMES =================== --
local frm1 = CreateFrame("Frame", "GraphDPS main graph frame", UIParent)
frm1:SetSize(260, 80)
frm1:SetPoint("CENTER", UIParent, "CENTER", 0, 0 )
frm1.tex = frm1:CreateTexture()
frm1.tex:SetAllPoints(frm1)
frm1.tex:SetColorTexture(0,0,0,fra)
frm1:EnableDrawLayer("ARTWORK")

-- =================================== EVENTS =================================== --
frm1:RegisterEvent("ADDON_LOADED")
frm1:RegisterEvent("PLAYER_LOGOUT")
frm1:RegisterEvent("PLAYER_REGEN_DISABLED")
frm1:RegisterEvent("PLAYER_REGEN_ENABLED")
frm1:RegisterEvent("COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED")
local function eventH(self, event, ...)
    if event == "PLAYER_LOGOUT" then 
        GDPS_frgfh = frm1:GetWidth()
        GDPS_frgfw = frm1:GetHeight()
        GDPS_db1 = db1
        GDPS_db3 = db3
        GDPS_damae = damae
        GDPS_unvu = unvu
    end
    if event == "ADDON_LOADED" then
        db1 = GDPS_db1
        db3 = GDPS_db3
        demae = GDPS_damae
    end
    if event == "PLAYER_REGEN_DISABLED" then
        tmprd = tmr()
        colib = "Combat actuel"
        tic = 0
        tmdce = 1
        datalc = 0
        db1ad(tmprd, "cs")
        db3={}
        tic = C_Timer.NewTicker(1, function()
            if tmia - db1le[1] > 1 then db1ad(db1le[1]+1, 0) end
            if tmia < tmlcs + cosc then db1ad(db1le[1]+1, 0) end 
            cosc = cosc + 1
            tmdce = tmdce + 1
        end)
    end
    if event == "PLAYER_REGEN_ENABLED" then
        tic:Cancel()
        colib = "Dernier combat"
        cosc = 0
        tmcel = tmr()
        if db1le[1] ~= tmia or db1le[2] == "cs" then db1ad(tmia, tmiaa) end
        tmdce = 0
        for i = db1le[1] + 1, tmce - 1 do
            db1ad(i, 0)
            tmdce = tmdce + 1
        end
        db1ad(tmcel, "ce")
        tmia = 0
        tmiaa = 0
        tmce = tmcel
    end
    if event == "COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED" then
        if colib == "Combat actuel" then
            tmoe, evt, _, unUIDe = select(1, CombatLogGetCurrentEventInfo())
            tmoe = mathfloor(tmoe)
            -- l'ajout des pet reste à voir
            if unvu[unUIDe] ~= nil then
                if evt == "SWING_DAMAGE" then
                    eva = select(12, CombatLogGetCurrentEventInfo())
                    evsn = "swing"
                elseif evt == "SPELL_DAMAGE" or evt == "SPELL_PERIODIC_DAMAGE" or evt == "RANGE_DAMAGE" then
                    evsn, _, eva = select(13, CombatLogGetCurrentEventInfo())
                end
                if evt == "SWING_DAMAGE" or evt == "SPELL_DAMAGE" or evt == "SPELL_PERIODIC_DAMAGE" or evt == "RANGE_DAMAGE" then
                    if type(eva) == "number" then
                        if eva > damae then
                            damae = eva
                        end
                        if db3[evsn] ~= nil then
                            db3[evsn] = db3[evsn] + eva
                        else
                            db3[evsn] = eva
                        end            
                        if tmia ~= 0 then
                            if tmia == tmoe then
                                tmiaa = tmiaa + eva
                            else
                                db1ad(tmia, tmiaa)
                                tmia = tmoe
                                tmiaa = eva
                            end
                        else
                            tmia = tmoe
                            tmiaa = eva
                        end
                    end
                    datalc = datalc + eva
                end
            --else
                -- l'ajout des dégâts des invoqués viendra après
            end
        end
    end
end
frm1:SetScript("OnEvent", eventH)


It may be necessary to monitor the growth of tables db1, db3 and unvu, because they are saved and restored.

unvu has just one entry ; db3 deleted, still the same problem. I think my problem is db1 but i don't know what to do

try if #db1 >= db1l then... and  in function db1doe() you can be safe and  use for i=1,#db1-db1l do table.remove(db1, 1) end

Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try it tonight.

It seems that the problem was that I had both a timer updated every second and a subscription to combat events. When a combat event occurred at the same time as the timer update, lua being synchronous, it created a bug. I deleted the timer and after almost three hours of play, no more problem. I'm testing again. If it is confirmed I will publish an auto-answer that will maybe help other people.

It was not actually a table problem.
In this code there is a timer that triggers actions every second and a frame that listens to different events.
I deleted the timer and there is no more problem.
I think that when an event was received at the same precise moment or the timer had to execute its actions it generated a freeze.
I will do tests using coroutines, which, if I understand correctly, are used precisely to avoid this kind of situation.
